# Cannot deploy app to Heroku "Could not read from remote repository"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github, ssh-keys

I am currently learning RUBY and trying to complete a french version of Michael Hartl tutorial.

Though I am blocked at some point of the tutorial. 
I can't deploy my app to heroku, and get the following :

> *git push heroku master
>
>   Permission denied (publicKey)
>
>   fatal: could not read from remote repository*

Though:

- I have the two id_rsa and id_rsa.pub in my .ssh folder (in Win7)
- It seems I have remoted my Rails app to github successfully. The repository indeed shows the app files.
- I have successfully created the Heroku app and see it on my dashboard.

regarding SSH keys :

I have followed the following for adding publick SSH key to Github : https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

I have aswell completed the following on deploying an heroku app (and adding keys to Heroku): https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git

Though I still get this message.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely either deploying with mis-matched SSH keys, *or* you haven't deployed your keys to Heroku yet. According to [the documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys):

> A common key error is: Permission denied (publickey). You can fix this by using keys:add to notify Heroku of your new key.

Resolve this error by pushing your keys to Heroku:

```
# Using the Heroku CLI Toolbelt (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command)
heroku keys:add
```

If possible, you'll want to keep a single set of SSH keys on your system so that there's no confusion as to which keys you're deploying with.

Comment: Just to make sure everything was fine, i have reset my SSH Keys from Git bash : ssh-keygen -t rsa , and then copied the pub key from the file to my github account keys tab. I have added the keys back on heroku from my command prompt: Heroku keys:add , which gave me a successful result of keys copied over. Still same issue

Comment: Yet, when running the following in git bash : ssh -vT git@github.com i get the following selected lines: debug1: identity file /c/Users/Maxence/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Maxence/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/Maxence/.ssh/id_dsa type -1

Comment: How many SSH keys do you have in your `.ssh` directory? Can you post the contents of that entire directory? Heroku is _very_ finicky with multiple keys – as a result, many users end up resolving this issue by deleting all keys but one.

Comment: I have only 3 files: id_rsa (type:File), id_rsa (type: PUB File), known_hosts (Type:File)

Comment: Does it work to issue `heroku keys:clear` from the CLI, then `heroku keys:add`?

Comment: first commenad gives successful : Removing all SSH keys... done, second one gives a successful message of a found existing public key id_rsa.pub, and successfull uploading of such. Though same issue

Comment: If you type `heroku keys` from the command line, does it return the contents of exactly one key – the key in your `.ssh` directory?

Comment: it shows: ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC...u1Wb+1dQ== Maxence@MAXENCE-PC  which is indeed matching the few first characters of the Pub key file once opened with notepad. It seems I cant see the whole key from the command prompt as shown above.

Comment: moreover, on github side, I get the same fingerprint from the ssh-keygen -t rsa command in git bash than the one provided by Git hub from the web interface, when the pub key is pasted over and validated..